# How to add Item to Static Property Typeof List?

Tags: c#, static

I have a util class like this:

```
public class Util
{
  static public List<Person> PersonList{get;set;}
}
```

I want add Item to my list in Main method like this:

```
void Main()
{
    Util.PersonList.Add(new Person{ Name="A" });  
}
```

But it impossible ...PersonList is null?

Comment: You should initialize the list before you begin adding, ain't you?

Comment: I would recommend to entirely avoid using static list.
Consider constructing it in the to most class and passing it across over constructors of collaborator classes if you need it at multiple places.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add static constructor to your static class

```
public class Util
{
  static Util()
  {
     PersonList = new List<Person>();
  }
  static public List<Person> PersonList{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: You don't need to set public to constructor?

Comment: No,static constructor can only be private. Check this link about static constructors http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @Stecya if i have many list like PersonList in Util Class i must create instance from any Property in my Static constructor ?

Comment: Yes, you need to initialize all objects in constructor